# Transitioning from devise to roll-your-own auth in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I got started building an app which 20-30 people are currently using.  I used devise, and I'm now wishing I had not...  for reasons such as ease of adding a [guest user](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record), etc.

I think I want to remove devise, and follow the Hartl tutorial to create my own authorization.

Has anyone done this before?  Do you have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Advice: get started! Post back here with **specific** questions about issues you run into along the way.

Comment: I'm working on the Hartl tutorial, and it seems like all I need to do is rename the encrypted_password column to password_digest and add the has_secure_password line...  Could it really be that simple?!  I'll give it a shot in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Definitely start with Michael Hartl's tutorial. It is really comprehensive, detailed and very well written. More importantly, he always places an emphasis in security. So yeah, his tutorial is surely the way to go.

Good luck!